# Clear internal buffer of node-red join node

Tags: join, node-red

Is there no way of clearing the internal buffer of a "join" node?

i'm using it in manual mode to collect mqtt topics and messages as a key-value object.

Join settings are:

Combine each `msg.payload` to create a `key/value object` using the value of `msg.topic` as key send value after `1` part `X` and every subsequent message

Every once a while i want to reset the generated object and the only way i have figured out to do so is to restart node red.

Is there a special msg that i can pass to the node to reset the internal buffer?

Answer (score 0):

The closest option is to send a message with `msg.complete` set to something (e.g. true) this will reset the counters for each message part and cause the `join` node to output it's current state. So if the `join` node was configured to wait for 4 messages and it had only received 2 when the `msg.complete` arrives it will output a message with 2 items and then reset.

This is described in the info sidebar for the join node.

Comment: That do not reset the output object in my case.
Join settings are:
Combine each `msg.payload`
to create a `key/value object`
using the value of `msg.topic` as key
send value after `1` part `X` and every subsequent message